# Color picker for tinting image (HTML, CSS, web)

Tags: jquery, html, css, colors, picker

I'm trying to find a good solution to use one image, but use CSS/HTML or something lightweight to apply a filter or tint on top of the image.

For instance,

[image]

Ideally, I would like to only use 1 image on the page, and just place a transparent filter/image on top based on the color picker off to the side, but haven't done it off to to the side like this before.

Thanks

Comment: Please show su the code you have so far.

Comment: You should be looking for something like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not going to code it out for you but rather point you in the right direction.

Start here with css3 filters --> http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

This will show you how you can apply filters to images and change the colours as you want.

Next for your colour picker you would make some sorta javascript that when a specific colour is picked it would change the class of that image. Something like...

`document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "MyClass";`

or

```
document.getElementById(id).style.property=new style
```

Using something like

```
 <button onclick="yourColourPickerFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This solution is quite hacky but it also works in browsers that do not support CSS3 filters like Internet Explorer 11 or Firefox 22.

```css
.outer {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url("http://stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/5QWUZ3XYGE.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
}
#inner1 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(180,0,0,0.4);
}
#inner2 {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0,0,180,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner1">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div id="inner2">
  </div>
</div>
```